# Is there an easy way to check if a sequence repeats locally?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have come up with a sequence of digits (1-3) that I think never repeats locally. There should be no bits where a block of digits is immediately followed by the same digits so 213 can't be followed by 213 etc.

I got the idea from a sequence mentioned in this video by Matt Parker:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=prh72BLNjIk

I was colouring this mandala pattern in a colouring book and noticed a ring of 132 rectangles and thought it would be nice to colour in a pattern of red yellow and blue that doesn't repeat unless you go around the circle multiple times. Hope that makes sense.

The sequence I came up with is:
123132312323121321231321312132123121312313212312131231312321323121321232132312321231213231232123121231321312321323132131231323123213
(I'm trying to write the sequence so that if you take the 1st 44 digits and replace 1 with 2, 2 with 3 and 3 with 1 - you get the 2nd 44 digits. This way there would be a nice symmetry to the pattern)

I had a little look and couldn't find any repetition and wondered if anyone could think of a quick way to check rather than manually checking every group of digits.

Thank you

Comment: This repeats $23$ starting from the ninth entry.

Comment: damn it. okay my question now  is can this sequence be done with the parameters I set? If so, how can I fix it?

thanks for spotting the error

Comment: The [Thue-Morse sequence](http://www.cs.umb.edu/~offner/files/thue.pdf) is helpful for generating square free strings.  Also, [this link](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9662/what-is-the-fastest-way-to-count-square-free-words) gives a nice explicit discussion of some algorithmic ways to test if a string is square free.

Comment: If you are trying to create a periodic sequence that never repeats itself, you won't succeed (by virtue of it being periodic). Reason: Let block size=length of period of sequence, results in a block that is repeated immediately after itself.